# how to parse values with different delimiter in python

Tags: python

I have `"2-20,41"`. How do I parse this in python when the third value is not always there. It could be 
case 1=`"2-20"`, case 2=`"2-20,41"`,case 3=`"2-20,41,42"`.

I need to check if my value `x` is in the range or equal to what is after comma. There may be one value after a comma, or two different value after two different comma.

Comment: Can you include an example input and output showing the desired outcomes?

Comment: sorry, basically I have one value, x=10, and a range of number [2,20], so case 1: x=10 , in range of [2,10] then it will return true. case 2: if x=41, and checked range 2-20, plus the third number 41, then the return is also true. My problem is with the third value 41, may or may not be there, How do I check my value x = to 41 or not?

Comment: Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> re.search('^(\d+)-(\d+)((,\d+){0,2})$','2-20').groups()
('2', '20', '', None)
>>> re.search('^(\d+)-(\d+)((,\d+){0,2})$','2-20,41').groups()
('2', '20', ',41', ',41')
>>> re.search('^(\d+)-(\d+)((,\d+){0,2})$','2-20,41,42').groups()
('2', '20', ',41,42', ',42')
```

Comment: ```re.split(r'[-,]', s)```

Comment: @wwii That would be easier for sure. But maybe the poster wants a stricter assumption.

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in '2-30,40,50,100'.split(','):
   parts = i.split('-')
   if len(parts) == 2:
     if n >= int(parts[0]) and n <= int(parts[1]):
       print 'match'
       break
   elif n == int(parts[0]):
     print 'match'
     break
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help. Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers.